# How can I stick buttons to one another in TableLayout?

Tags: java, android

[image]

1) How can I make all buttons stick to one another so that there is no space between any 2 buttons?
2) How can I make the picture of the bomb be inside the button as backround(I have  it done wrongly)
Here is some code how I added image:

```
clickedButton.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        int newWidth = clickedButton.getWidth();
        int newHeight = clickedButton.getHeight();
        Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b64);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        Resources resource = getResources();
        clickedButton.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(resource, scaledBitmap));
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make them stick together I would try removing any possible margins, since you already tried padding. If it doesn't work I would try to work some negative values that might do what I wanted.

As for the images in the buttons, I think you could use `ImageButton` instead of button. Once it is clicked, it changes the background image (or not, I don't understand your game[?]).

Comment: Did you play MinesSweeper?

Comment: Yes. So now I understand the game. Haha

Comment: thank you, I played with negative margin and made it correctly :)